# Using C to Call Dynamic Cpp Library

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

My goal is to be able to create a C library wrapper for a Cpp library.

I have:

1. libcpp.so, a dynamic library written in Cpp by someone else
2. libc.so,   a dynamic library written in C by me to wrap libcpp
3. test.c,    a simple problem to test whether it works.

My problem is that I cannot compile libc.so correctly such that I can access features from libcpp.so from test.c

Example Code:

```
//libc.h
extern "C" void * createNetwork();

//libc.cpp
#include "libc.h"
#include <libcpp.h>  // <- unsure about this

void * createObject()
{
    Object * foo = new Object();
    void * retval = foo;
    return retval;
}

//test.c
#include <stdio.h>
void * createObject();

int main()
{
    void * bar = createObject();
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling using

```
// COMPILE LIBC
g++ -Wall -fPIC -c libc.cpp -L/opt/lib -llibcpp
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libc.so.1 -o libc.so.1.0   *.o
sudo mv libc.so.1.0 /opt/lib
sudo ln -sf /opt/lib/libc.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libc.so.1
sudo ln -sf /opt/lib/libc.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libc.so

// COMPILE TEST.C
gcc -Wall test.c -L/opt/lib -lc -o test
```

How do I properly include libcpp in libc?

How do I properly include libc in test.c?

Do I need header files in addition to just the dynamic libraries?

Comment: Um just a notice, but libc might a bit dangerous name to use. I am not sure what name it uses on system, but generally there is something named libc already. Also what error do you get? Might be useful information.

Comment: FYI, C++ has a mechanism to create C-callabel functions `extern "C"`, C does not have a facility to call C++ functions.

Comment: @Deduplicator But OP uses it. It is the only content of `libc.h`. Is it used wrongly? The only problem I see so far is `libcpp.h` which existence is not confirmed. It seems like `Object` should be defined there. But its been years since I compiled an `.so` by hand. I'm not good enough to guess without an error message.

Comment: Q1: do you have source code to the C++ library?  If yes, things may be a bit easier; if not then there is a lot more trickery you have to do.
Q2: if you don't have C++ library code, do you have an understanding of name mangling in C++?

Comment: @luk32: Yes, it is, because the header is no longer C.

Comment: @luk32 - Thanks for the advice. The actual library names are less dangerous, I just used those for question clarity.                        I am glad you brought up libcpp.h. I do have a header file for it, but do I need that header file to compile libc? Also, do I need test.c to have access to my header from libc in order to get it working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard mechanism should look something like this:

**mylib.h:**

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void * createThing();

void destroyThing(void *);

// more things to operate on the object

#ifndef __cplusplus
}  // extern "C"
#endif
```

**magic_lib.cpp:**

```
#include "magic_thing.hpp"
#include "mylib.h"

void * createThing()
{ return new MagicThing; }

void destroyThing(void * p)
{ delete static_cast<MagicThing *>(p); }
```

**Usage** (in C)**:**

```
#include "mylib.h"

int main(void)
{
    void * p = createThing();

    // ...  use p ...

    destroyThing(p);
}
```

If you don't like void pointers, you could add a type alias like `typedef void * ThingHandle` or so.

Comment: So this is what @Deduplicator was trying to tell. lol. Call me stupid but code is so much more understandable than words...

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was able to get it to run. Kerrek's solution worked and I had to compile with 'g++ -Wall test.c libc.cpp -L/opt/lib -lc -o test'

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to create functions callable by C and C++ is using preprocessor conditionals looking for `__cplusplus`, wrapping the whole header in an `extern "C"` block if it is defined, and not using any C++ extensions.
Thus the header is C and C++. (Optionally one can conditionally add static and non-virtual functions for better C++ integration if `__cplusplus` is defined)

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  // Many functions
  // Forward-declarations of used classes using struct like this:
  typedef struct my_class myclass;
  // defined structs may include additional
  //  static and non-virtual member-functions if C++ defined
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then you can build your library in either one, though as it shall facilitate calls to a C++ library you should use C++ for a robust library.
The compiler should warn you if you include the header but forget the `extern "C"` in C++.

Comment: *Not sure where to put it, but I choose your answer.* So `extern "C"` will produce an error with c compiler and the c program won't compile. Is that it?

Comment: Yes. That's the important part.

Comment: Now its all clear. Sorry for stupid questions, but without error and unresponsive OP, and lack of experience it was quite hard to get. Thanks for clarifying everything.